# How to Select Multiple values using a condition?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro

I have an attribute Field with 3 different values such as "Move", "Move, Copy" and "Draw, Copy, Move" . I have to select them and export them to a new shapefile.

```
import arcpy

in_data = 'C:/Users/angelin/Desktop/Dallas_3_22.6.22_COMPLETED/Dallas_Property_Points_Part-3.shp'
arcpy.env.workspace = in_data
Moved_Features = 'C:/Users/angelin/Desktop/Dallas_3_22.6.22_COMPLETED/Moved_Features.shp'

Move = arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(in_data, "NEW_SELECTION", "Distance > 0 ")
fc = ["RL_Remarks"]
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(Points, fc) as cursor:
    for row1 in cursor:
        if (row1[0] == "Move" and row1[0] == "Draw,Copy,Move" and row1[0] == "Copy,Move"):
        return  
             
            
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(Move, Moved_Features )
```

Comment: But that is for splitting attributes right? i want the mutiple values in the field to be selected and exported

Comment: Create one where clause and use [Select](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/2.8/tool-reference/analysis/select.htm), dont use a cursor

Comment: Lemme try this one

Comment: Im getting an error in SelectLayerByAttribute

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for a cursor. Create one where clause using [add field delimiters](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/2.8/arcpy/functions/addfielddelimiters.htm), and [Select](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/2.8/tool-reference/analysis/select.htm) to create a new feature class

```
import arcpy

in_data = 'C:/Users/angelin/Desktop/Dallas_3_22.6.22_COMPLETED/Dallas_Property_Points_Part-3.shp'
Moved_Features = 'C:/Users/angelin/Desktop/Dallas_3_22.6.22_COMPLETED/Moved_Features.shp'
fieldname = 'Field123' #Change to match the name of your field

def delim(dataSource, fieldName):
    """Add field delimiters around a fieldname)"""
    return arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(datasource=dataSource, field=fieldName)

sql = """{0} IN{1} AND {2}>0""".format(delim(in_data, fieldname), ('Move', 'Move, Copy', 'Draw, Copy, Move'), delim(in_data, 'Distance'))

arcpy.analysis.Select(in_features=in_data, out_feature_class=Moved_Features, where_clause=sql)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try build correct query

```py
    selection = 'Field == "Move" or Field == "Draw,Copy,Move" or Field == "Copy,Move"'
    Move = arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(in_data, "NEW_SELECTION", selection)
    arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(Move, Moved_Features )`
```

Comment: I tried this code and im getting an execution error

Comment: ExecuteError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
In  [18]:
Line 21:    Mo = arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(in_data, "NEW_SELECTION", selection)

File C:\Users\angelin\AppData\Local\Programs\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\management.py, in SelectLayerByAttribute:
Line 10293: retval = convertArcObjectToPythonObject(gp.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(*gp_fixargs((in_layer_or_view, selection_type, where_clause, invert_where_clause), True)))
ExecuteError: ERROR 000358: Invalid expression
Failed to execute (SelectLayerByAttribute).