# Using Search Cursor results to Select Features by Attributes

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, cursor

I've been working on automating the workflow with Python for a product that I create on a weekly basis. Where I'm stuck now is I have a filtered point file which I want to use its attributes to filter another point file as the attributes "Events" are the same in both.

The search cursor will return all the unique events within the "layername"

```
lyr = "layername"
events = arcpy.da.SearchCursor(lyr, ['Event'])
unique_events = list(set([row[0] for row in events]))
unique_events
print(unique_events)
```

I'm very new to Python and don't understand how to use the results to create a query to then select by attributes in the other point layer file.

Comment: Look at how I create a sql query in [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/435656/how-to-select-multiple-values-using-a-condition/435660#435660)

Comment: Thanks! What is Moved_Features? and where is the specific location for datasource?

Comment: It is there, at row 4

Comment: Have you followed any of the suggestions/replies on Esri Community where you cross posted the question?  [Building SQL Expression using printed results?](https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-pro-questions/building-sql-expression-using-printed-results/m-p/1196967#M57914)

Comment: Yes! and this worked for me.

Comment: sql = "Event IN(" + ','.join(map(str,unique_events)) + ")"
arcpy.management.SelectLayerByAttribute("lyr2", "NEW_SELECTION", sql, None)